# PageViewer setting Height/Width

Tags: web-part, custom-web-part-property

i am creating a dynamic Page Viewer web part from the user control code behind .. something like this:

```
PageViewerWebPart oWebPart = new PageViewerWebPart(); 
oWebPart.ContentLink = WebPart.WebPartContentLink.ToString(); 
Controls.Add(oWebPart);
```

the problem i am having is Height/Width.... do i need to provide user to set the height and width for the Page Viewer in the Prop window?

```
oWebPart.Height = "<user input>" 
oWebPart.Width  = "user input>"
```

any help how should i deal with this issue?

I try to set the Height/Width of the web part that i have created through:

```
Appearance>>>Height/Width
```

but no avail.

custom web part for Page Viewer web part through code-behind but i am unable to set height and width after i edit my custom web part and i select inches and set to 12 but nothing has happen...

Any Insight?

Answer (score 1):

I have a brief description of how to the user can update the nested web part with the default properties editor [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9842/is-there-a-way-to-override-default-generated-properties-in-a-custom-web-part/17516#17516).

Basically, you would write something like this in your code-behind:

```
oWebPart.Height = this.Height  
oWebPart.Width  = this.Width
```

That way, your nested page viewer web part will inherit what the user typed.

The page viewer web part is just an `<iframe>` element in the HTML, while your web part is most likely a `<div>` element surrounding it. By default the `<iframe>` has a fixed size, which is why the default properties resizing the `<div>` appears to disregard resizing the page viewer.